# How to use .some() for all values in an array with different objects

Tags: javascript

For example I have this array:

```js
const ageArr = [{tom: 24}, {jack: 20}, {anna: 30}]
```

How can I use `.some()` to search all of the values without specifying the name?

Expected:

```js
if (ageArr.some((el) => el > 19)) {
  console.log('Some of them are older than 19')
}
//Output: People are older than 19
```

Comment: _"...without specifying the name?"_ - How about using a more suitable object/structure: `{ name: "Tom", age: 24 }` - That would make this so much easier...

Comment: I agree with @Andreas. The (currently) proposed solutions with Object.keys/values are hacky and could easily break if your data changes (for instance if the objects get another property). Using a suitable data format would be much cleaner and less error prone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cherryblossom provided the best way of solving this problem using the function `Object.values`

If you're concerned about browser compatibility, keep in mind that the functions `some` and `Object.keys` works even on Internet Explorer, while `Object.values` doesn't

```js
if (ageArr.some((el) => el[Object.keys(el)[0]] > 19)) {
  console.log('People are older than 19')
}
```

I would expand the arrow function like this:

```js
ageArr.some((el) => { 
    const key = Object.keys(el)[0];
    const value = el[key];
    return value > 19;
}
```

Comment: It's easy to polyfill those methods which are not available. And arrow functions don't work in IE

Comment: You're right, arrow functions are not available in IE.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) function to get the values of the objects:

```js
const ageArr = [{tom: 24}, {jack: 20}, {anna: 30}]

if (ageArr.some((el) => Object.values(el)[0] > 19)) {
  console.log('People are older than 19')
}
```

Here are some examples of what `Object.values` does:

```js
[
  {tom: 24},
  {foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux'},
  {}
].forEach(x => console.log(`Object.values(${JSON.stringify(x)}) ==`, Object.values(x)))
```